# msbuild for visual studio 2008 projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

We have a relatively big C++ application with lots of dependencies. On our build server running msbuild 4.0.30319, we keep getting linker errors and failures when doing incremental builds using msbuild.

After further investigating this, it does appear to be that dependency libraries are not being picked up and built prior to building the application.

The question i have is as follows:
Are there best practices for building such a C++ project with dependencies? if yes, what is the correct way to do incremental builds using MSBUILD for a C++ application built using VS2008 with a fair amount of dependencies.

Comment: IMHO, build servers should be making full builds, not incremental builds.  The developers can make incremental builds on their workstations.  Performing a full build provides more confidence in the deliverable.

Comment: Hi Thomas, we do indeed do full builds. In fact, we do both an incremental and a full. Thanks for the input but i am more interested how msbuild handles build dependencies on an incremental build and if it supports it

Comment: Have you setup the dependencies?  Right click on the solution (.sln) on the *Solution Explorer* and choose *Project Dependencies...*.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Thomas comment "*build servers should be making full builds, not incremental builds.* "

When you create a new build definition on build server by default it does a **clean build for you every time**.  That is to say that between builds all the source from the previous build is deleted along with the compiled outputs and then the source is downloaded fresh, built and you are good to go.  There is a good reason for this to be the default – **it is the safest option**.  If your build script messes around with the files in your source directory at all (perhaps baking in a build number into the AssemblyInfo files etc) then you want to get a clean workspace to ensure that you are back to a known good state.

However, if you want to enable the incremental builds in build Server, like TFS, you can refer to the [Incremental Builds in Team Foundation Server](http://geekswithblogs.net/KirstinJ/archive/2008/05/27/incremental-builds-in-team-foundation-server.aspx) for more detail.

> but i am more interested how msbuild handles build dependencies on an incremental build and if it supports it

Dependencies between projects could result in inconsistent builds. Visual Studio does respect project-to-project references and builds the reference project before the referring project. However, if several projects have a shared reference, that reference is built only once and “cached” for the next times it is referenced. Also, errors and exceptions on one build do not affect the running of other builds, which may depend on the failing build. For the more info, please refer to [Managed Incremental Build](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2007/03/02/managed-incremental-build/).